# Как завершить процесс скрипта python через модуль OS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос

Как завершить процесс скрипта python через модуль `OS`?

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под закрытием файла? Вы приняли ответ, в котором объясняется, как завершить процесс. Если Вы имели в виду именно это, отредактируйте вопрос, пожалуйста, чтобы в будущем не вводить в заблуждение других людей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модуль `os` в Python предоставляет функции для взаимодействия с операционной системой. `os` входит в состав стандартных служебных модулей Python. Этот модуль обеспечивает переносимый способ использования функций, зависящих от операционной системы.

Метод `os._exit()` в Python используется для выхода из процесса с указанным статусом без вызова обработчиков очистки, очистки буферов `stdio` и т.д.

Примечание. Этот метод обычно используется в дочернем процессе после системного вызова `os.fork()`. Стандартный способ выхода из процесса - метод `sys.exit(n)`.

> Syntax: `os._exit(status)`
>
> Parameter:
>
> `status`: целое число или определенные выше значения, представляющие статус выхода..

Comment: Ваш ответ принят, а значит, автор имел в виду именно это. Но всё же вопрос был про закрытие файла, а ответ про завершение процесса. Как Вы поняли, о чём речь?